# Rails: How to stream data to and from a binary column (blob)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, blob

I have a question about how to efficiently store and retrieve large amounts of data to and from a blob column (data_type :binary).  Most examples and code out there show simple assignments but that cannot be efficient for large amounts of data.  For instance storing data from a file may be something like this:

```
# assume a model MyFileStore has a column blob_content :binary

my_db_rec = MyFileStore.new
File.open("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/alargefile.txt", "rb") do |f|
  my_db_rec.blob_content = f.read
end
my_db_rec.save
```

Clearly this would read the entire file content into memory before saving it to the database.  This cannot be the only way you can save blobs. For instance, in Java and in .Net there are ways to stream to and from a blob column so you are not pulling every thing into memory (see Similar Questions to the right).  Is there something similar in rails?  Or are we limited to only small chunks of data being stored in blobs when it comes to Rails applications.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Rails 4 you can use render stream.  Here's an example [Rails 4 Streaming](http://www.sitepoint.com/streaming-with-rails-4/)

I would ask though what database you're using, and if it might be better to store the files in a filesystem (Amazon s3, Google Cloud Storage, etc..) as this can greatly affect your ability to manage blobs.  Microsoft, for example, has this recommendation: [To Blob or Not to Blob](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525)

Uploading is generally done through forms, all at once or multi-part.  Multi-part chunks the data so you can upload larger files with more confidence.  The chunks are reassembled and stored in whatever database field (and type) you have defined in your model.

Downloads can be streamed.  There is a large tendency to hand off upload and streaming to third party cloud storage systems like amazon s3.  This drastically reduces the burden on rails.  You can also hand off upload duties to your web server.  All modern web servers have a way to stream files from a user.  Doing this avoids  memory issues as only the currently uploading chunk is in memory at any give time. The web server should also be able to notify your app once the upload is completed.

For general streaming of output:

To add a stream to a template you need to pass the :stream option from within your controller like this: `render stream: true`.  You also need to explicitly close the stream with `response.stream.close`.  Since the method of rendering templates and layouts changes with streaming, it is important to pay attention to loading attributes like title, etc.  This needs to be done with `content_for` not `yield`.  You can explicitly open and close streams using the Live API. For this you need the puma gem. Also be aware that you need a web server that supports streaming.  You can configure Unicorn to support streaming.

Comment: Thanks.  But render stream seams useful but how do I stream data into a blob column in the first place, efficiently.  I have seen the To Blob or Not to Blob article.  But the question really is how to do it in the first place.  I can see several advantages of blobs in DB.  One way to backup, one way to vertically scale, one disaster recovery, etc.  With S3 or other file stores, you now have two mechanisms for your data.

Comment: Can you point me to an example of how multipart upload are saved to a blob field by a Rails Controller.  I did not find any information on this.  For file uploads, it seems that rack middleware can handle multipart but when it gets to a rails controller every thing is in a params hash so either it is uploaded to a file or it is all in memory.  In general the problem I have is that there is no Rails ActiveRecord way of moving large data into a blob without sucking every thing into memory first.